# Find the Limit that Exists. If the limit does not exist explain why?

Tags: calculus

Can some show me a step by step example of how to do solve questions like this. No short cuts. I can do the rest by myself. I don't see an example in the book; thus, I have no idea how to solve these problems. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Search for the basic limit laws online, and see if they apply to each problem. For example, in part (a), you have $\lim_{x \to 2}[f(x)+5g(x)]=\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)+5\lim_{x \to 2}g(x)=4+(-2)(5)=-6$. In the instances that it does not exist, it is likely because it is indeterminate, such as in (e), where $h(x)=0$ is the denominator.

Link for limit laws: http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html

For part (a), you would apply the addition law and the constant law.

Answer (score 0):

All but (e) exist. (e) doesn't exist because its division by 0.